# RecyclerView not working on Fragment | Kotlin | Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to place a RecyclerView inside a Fragment. That recycler view gets all the data from Firebase and places the data on their proper location. I've already tried to make it diferent ways, but none of them worked and I don't know what to try more...
I've used some code, but it kept saying that my RecyclerView coudn't be empty.
This is the code i'm using now. I saw it on youtube, but it uses a function that dont even exists.

```
class InboxFragment : Fragment() {
    lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    lateinit var mDatabase: DatabaseReference

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false)

        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcView)
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notifications")

        logRecyclerView()

        return view
    }

    private fun logRecyclerView(){
        var FirebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Notifications, viewHolder>(
            Notifications::class.java,
            R.layout.inforow,
            viewHolder::class.java,
            mDatabase
        ){
            fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: viewHolder, model: Notifications, position: Int){
                viewHolder.itemView.txtTitle.text = model.titulo
                viewHolder.itemView.txtDescription.text = model.descricao
                Picasso.get().load(model.img).into(viewHolder.itemView.imageItem)
            }
        }

        mRecyclerView.adapter = FirebaseRecyclerAdapter
    }


    class viewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    }
}
```

This is my `inforow` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageItem"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageItem"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="286dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2.6dp"
        android:text="Description"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageItem"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtTitle" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The class `Notification`

```
class Notifications {
     //Nome do evento
     var titulo: String? = null

     //Sítio onde se realiza
     var localizacao: String? = null

     //URL que redireciona para a página específica
     var urlPag: String? = null

     //Descição do evento
     var descricao: String? = null

     //Imagem
     var img: String? = null

     constructor(){

     }

     constructor(titulo: String?, localizacao: String?, urlPag: String?, descricao: String?, img: String?) {
          this.titulo = titulo
          this.localizacao = localizacao
          this.urlPag = urlPag
          this.descricao = descricao
          this.img = img
     }
}
```

[image: This is a photo from my Firebase:]

[image: Code Error]

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code lies in the fact that you have different names for your properties in the database than in your Notifications class. Basically, those are the Portuguese versions of the properties in the database, which is not correct. The names must match. To solve this you should use an annotation for each property as in the following lines of code:

```
@get:PropertyName("title")
@set:PropertyName("title")
@PropertyName("title")
var titulo: String? = null,
```

Comment: Btw, that's Portuguese, not Spanish ;)

Comment: I should put that on my class? I've already done it, but it still gives me error on logRecyclerView...I'll add na image

Comment: You should those annotations in your `Notifications` class. Does it work that way?